# Wheel-Spinning Probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I saw this problem a while ago and a found the same answer as the textbook, yet I wasn’t truly sure if that was correct. Here was the problem:

> You have a wheel with 4 equal sections, red, yellow, green and blue. Another wheel has 3 equal sections: red, yellow, and green. Knowing that exactly 1 wheel landed green, what are the odds the second wheel was the one that did so.

I immediately counted: if the first when is green, there are 2 possibilities for the second wheel: red and yellow. If however the second wheel landed green, there are 3 possibilities for the first wheel. Red, yellow and blue. I hence concluded there are 3 out of 5 possibilities in which the second wheel was green, so the answer is 3/5. This however doesn’t seem correct as we didn’t account for the fact that the first wheel has 4 sections, and the second has 3. Am I correct, or is there something I didn’t account for? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are making use of the number of sections when counting the possibilities. $4 - 1 = 3$ and $3 - 1 = 2$. Just be careful, the question is asking for the odds and not the probability.

Comment: I’m sorry, but could you explain what the difference between the two are? I’m new to this…

Comment: Probability refers to the ratio of number of favorable outcome to that of total outcomes. Odds would be the ratio of favorable outcomes to unfavorable outcomes. For an event $E$, the odds in favor and $P(E)$ have the relation:
$$\text{Odds} = \frac{P(E)}{1 - P(E)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is small so we can brute force it by counting to have certainty in the calculation.

The possible outcomes are (using 1-4 for colors, wheel 1 then wheel 2):

11
12
13
21
22
23
31
32
33
41
42
43

Of these, there are 5 spins with exactly one green (#1), and of these 3 of them are in the second wheel, 2 in the first, so the odds are 3:2. The probability is $\frac{3}{5}=0.6$

But then brute force is usually not possible, and the more compact route to the solution would be:

Probability of green only in wheel 2: $\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{4}$

Probability of green only in wheel 1: $\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$

Odds: $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{3}{2}$

Probability: $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{12}+\frac{3}{12}}=\frac{12}{20}=\frac{3}{5}$